# Is this not that way to make an Italian flag .ppm file?

Tags: c, ppm

This is my code to create an Italian flag .ppm file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int width = 800, height = 600, i, j;

   printf("P6\n");
   printf("%d %d\n", width, height);
   printf("255\n");

   for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width/3; j++) {
            printf("%c%c%c", 0,146,70);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < width/3; j++) {
            printf("%c%c%c", 255, 255, 255);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < width/3; j++) {
            printf("%c%c%c", 206,43,55);
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I've already made a Poland and Netherlands flag and it worked well. I don't know if it's right?

Comment: *I don't know if it right* - what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Instead of all this `printf` junk, just write *raw bytes*. Tip: Compose using a buffer of the correct size, populate it, then dump it all out in one shot using something like `fwrite`.

Comment: If you don't know if it's right, you can look at the resulting image file.I took your code, compiled it with `gcc tmp.c -o tmp.exe` and saved the image file with `./tmp.exe > tmp.ppm`

Comment: If this is the right code to create an Italian flag .ppm file. The numbers are just the r, g, b codes for the certain colors. This code is suppose to create a .ppm file of the flag of Italy. I just need to find the right pattern.

Comment: Does the resulting image look like an Italian flag?

Comment: @lucidbrot Yeah I tried that but when I open the file it says "failed: PNM Image plug-in could not open image" which I know means my code is wrong.

Comment: Then why are you asking "is it right" if you know it is wrong?

Comment: @osit0_solit0 IrfanView opened it without issue for me. But yeah, your total number of pixels is probably lower than what the first few bytes promise. So it's valid to say the image is invalid.

Comment: @tadman I was able to do the Poland and Netherlands flag right. I think it's just my for loops are wrong, plus I haven't learned that yet, so I really don't know how to that.

Comment: It's really a lot easier than doing it this way because you'd just set `buffer[n] = ...` and such, filling in the pixels with the correct offsets and colors. I'd go so far as to write a wrapper function that you can give `x, y` coordinates and `r, g, b` values and it will write in the appropriate location, plus an inverse one that can read out RGB values. This will help shape your understanding as the file itself is basically a binary buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `width = 800` is not divisible by 3. So you don't fill the whole row with one iteration of the outer loop.

```c
for (j = 0; j < width/3; j++)
```

This line stops once `j` is greater than a third of the width. Let's consider a simple example with `width=4`. `width/3` is somewhere between 1 and 2. So you would color one pixel green, one pixel white, one pixel red. And the fourth? That has to be filled by the next iteration.

Set your `width = 900` for example, and you should get the expected output.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. Those were just numbers from another flag's ratio, and I forgot to change them. Careless mistake of me. I know there a more advanced ways of doing this, but I'm just starting off with c, so hopefully later on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @lucidbrot is correct, but I want to elaborate a little bit.

`800/3` is `266` (assuming integer division), and `266*3` is `798`, not the width of `800` you wanted. Naturally you could select a width divisible by `3` to solve the problem as @lucidbrot suggested.

Sometimes you don't have the liberty to change the width, but luckily there is another solution. Don't divide the colors in equal parts. The easiest is to calculate where each colorband starts, relative to the start of the scanline, and just stop coloring with one color where the next starts:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int width = 800, height = 600;

   printf("P6\n");
   printf("%d %d\n", width, height);
   printf("255\n");

   int start_green = 0;
   int start_white = (1*width)/3;
   int start_red = (2*width)/3
   

   for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        /* Green Band */
        for (int j = start_green; j < start_white; j++) {
            printf("%c%c%c", 0,146,70);
        }
        /* White Band */
        for (int j = start_white; j < start_red; j++) {
            printf("%c%c%c", 255, 255, 255);
        }
        /* Red Band */ 
        for (int j = start_red; j < width; j++) {
            printf("%c%c%c", 206,43,55);
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Some additional comments to `start_white` and `start_red`. When doing integer multiplication and divisions, correct order of operator applications is important. `(2 * 800)/3` equals `533`. This is different than `2 * (800/3)` which equals `532`. So the first expression is closer to the real value of `533.3333....`.

Technically we don't need the parenthesis because of operator precedence, but it
is always a good idea to add clarity to the reader.

This method of dividing things in mostly equally sized groups have other uses. And then we typically can't change the number of "things" we have.

As an extra bonus question for the reader: What is the value of `800*(2/3)`, assuming integer division. Hint: it is not `533.3333....`.

Comment: Wow, this was really helpful. Your wording made me understand it, thanks!